# Will std::array template instances occupy more code memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdarray, code-size

I have a micro-controller that does not have an MMU, but we are using C and C++.

We are avoiding all dynamic memory usage (i.e. no `new SomeClass()` or `malloc()`) and most of the standard library.

Semi-Question 0:

From what I understand `std::array` does not use any dynamic memory so its usage should be OK (It is on the stack only). Looking at `std::array` source code, it looks fine since it creates a c-style array and then wraps functionality around that array.

The chip we are using has 1MB of flash memory for storing code.

Question 1:

I am worried that the use of templates in `std::array` will cause the binary to be larger, which will then potentially cause the binary to exceed the 1MB code memory limit.

I think if you create an instance of a `std::array< int, 5 >`, then all calls to functions on that `std::array` will occupy a certain amount of code memory, lets say X bytes of memory.

If you create another instance of `std::array< SomeObject, 5 >`, then call functions to that `std::array`, will each of those functions now be duplicated in the binary, thus taking up more code memory? X bytes of memory + Y bytes of memory.

If so, do you think the amount of code generated given the limited code memory capacity will be a concern?

Question 2:

In the above example, if you created a second `std::array< int, 10 >` instance, would the calls to functions also duplicate the function calls in the generated code? Even though both instances are of the same type, `int`?

Comment: Have you looked at the resulting assembly?

Comment: "We are avoiding all dynamic memory usage "  why?

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot 7 I don't have a micro in-front of me so I can't test this at the moment. I tested using visual studio on windows but I wasn't seeing any difference at all in the binary size changing.

Comment: Are you worried about *binary size* or *RAM*? The answers will be different. Also, are your `std::array`'s `static` or local to functions?

Comment: "1 MB of flash memory" ? flash typically holds code, not data.

Comment: @DOUGLAS O. MOEN We can't use dynamic memory because there is no MMU (memory management unit) on the micro-controller. Memory will get fragmented if you allocated and de-allocate a lot on this type of processor.
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-malloc-harmful-in-embedded-systems

Comment: @user9168101 I am worried about the binary size. Ram shouldn't matter as far as templates are concerned.

Comment: While MMU is useful, dynamic memory is not dependent on one.  C has been used for decades in very small microos, both malloc and free work fine, even though no MMU.  The two issues are independent.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN It's completely normal to be unable to use dynamic memory in microcontrollers / embedded systems. There are many reasons for it, some more valid than others, but when it comes down to it, there often isn't really a choice.

Comment: If the OP's system has no MMU *and* they're worried about fragmentation, it's likely that their coding style bans dynamic allocation too.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/UMnYkS Looks the same to me.. `std::array` is a struct with its only non-static member being a `T[size]` C style array where T is the type of element and size is a template parameter so it never has to actually store the size anywhere within the container.. In other words, this entire container boils down to a regular C style array and no extra cost.. only difference is that it has the added benefit of knowing its own size and use of iterators and other traits.

Comment: @Brandon Oh sorry i misread your comment at first. it seems that you are answering question 0. That answers the dynamic memory question! Thanks!

std::array adds some benefits that normal arrays don't have but they should be safe as far as dynamic memory is concerned, with minor overhead.

Comment: @user2654735; Most of it will be inlined and optimized out I guess.. What could you possibly use that isn't generic enough? `operator[]`, `count()`? I highly doubt the compiler will ever duplicate those methods.. Also only parts of a template class are duplicated (functions that are used.. and only if they're not generic enough to be re-used by multiple instantiations of the template).. Otherwise yes, your binary size will increase. As per comment above, the optimizer replaced `count()` with the template parameter and `[]` with array index operator (no duplication will be done)

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/p6NxZ5Qnzfo) could potentially help you

Comment: @ Brandon Yes this is my feeling exactly. I am looking at std:array and there doesn't seem to be that much going on, except they add some basic functionality like size() that I would like to use.

Comment: @Brandon I was mostly wondering if I create duplicate instances of std::array, are there going to be duplicates all over the place in the binary (even if the instances have the same primitive data type). I suppose the compiler would be able to use the same function calls from different instances as long as the data types are the same. Otherwise, if the data types are not the same, the compiler will definitely create a different instance of function definitions in the binary

Comment: @user2654735; `size()` is what I meant.. not `count`. Wrong terms. Since `size` is a template parameter, there's no duplication when using that function because all it does is return the template parameter value (a hardcoded integer you specified when making the arr).. the function will be inlined and optimized out such that the result is just the template parameter. For operator[], it does the same thing, it just forwards to `UnderlyingArray[index]` and is inlined. As far as I can tell, using just `operator[]` and `count()` gives zero overhead regardless of the amount of different types used.

Comment: @Brandon Nice! You are totally right! Taking it a step further, front, end, rend, rbegin etc etc seem to be doing the same thing, completely able to be optimized out by the compiler. I suppose swap() would be the only function call that could cause code bloat, maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::array` is considered a zero cost abstraction, which means it should be fairly optimizable by the compiler.

As of any zero cost abstraction, it may induce a small compile time penality, and if the opimizations required te be truely zero cost are not supported, then  it may incur a small size or runtime penality.

However, note that compiler are free to add padding at the end of a struct. Since `std::array` is a struct, you should check how your platform is handling `std::array`, but I highly doubt it's the case for you.

Take this array and `std::array` case:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

template<std::size_t n>
int stuff(const int(&arr)[n]) {
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0);
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    return stuff(arr);
}
```

---

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>

template<std::size_t n>
int stuff(const std::array<int, n>& arr) {
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0);
}

int main() {
    std::array arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    return stuff(arr);
}
```

Clang support this case very well. all cases with `std::array` or raw arrays are handleld the same way:

`-O2` / `-O3` both array and `std::array` with clang:

```
main: # @main
  mov eax, 21
  ret
```

However, GCC seem to have a problem optimizing it, for bith the `std::array` and the raw array case:

`-O3` with GCC for array and `std::array`:

```
main:
  movdqa xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
  movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40], xmm0
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rsp-32]
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-28]
  lea eax, [rdx+14+rax]
  ret
.LC0:
  .long 1
  .long 2
  .long 3
  .long 4
```

Then, it seem to optimize better with `-O2` in the case of raw array and fail with `std::array`:

`-O2` GCC `std::array`:

```
main:
  movabs rax, 8589934593
  lea rdx, [rsp-40]
  mov ecx, 1
  mov QWORD PTR [rsp-40], rax
  movabs rax, 17179869187
  mov QWORD PTR [rsp-32], rax
  movabs rax, 25769803781
  lea rsi, [rdx+24]
  mov QWORD PTR [rsp-24], rax
  xor eax, eax
  jmp .L3
.L5:
  mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx]
.L3:
  add rdx, 4
  add eax, ecx
  cmp rdx, rsi
  jne .L5
  rep ret
```

`-O2` GCC raw array:

```
main:
  mov eax, 21
  ret
```

It seem that the GCC bug failling to optimize `-O3` but succeed with `-O2` is fixed in the most recent build.

Here's a compiler explorer with all the [`O2`](https://godbolt.org/g/hb4nDd) and the [`O3`](https://godbolt.org/g/8ZrdXH)

---

With all these cases stated, you can see a common pattern:  No information about the `std::array` is outputted in the binary. There are no constructors, no `operator[]`, not even iterators, nor algorithms. Everything is inlined. Compiler are good at inlining simple functions. `std::array` member functions are usually very very simple.

> If you create another instance of std::array< SomeObject, 5 >, then call functions to that std::array, will each of those functions now be duplicated in the binary, thus taking up more flash memory? X bytes of memory + Y bytes of memory.

Well, you changed the data type your array is containing. If you manually add overload of all your functions to handle this additional case, then yes, all those new functions may take up some space. If your function are small, there is a great chance for them to be inlined and take less space. As you can see with the example above, inlining and constant folding may greatly reduce your binary size.

> In the above example, if you created a second std::array instance, would the calls to functions also duplicate the function calls in flash memory? Even though both instances are of the same type, int?

Again it depends. If you have many function templated in the size of the array, both `std::array` and raw arrays may "create" different function. But again, if they are inlined, there is no duplicate to be worried about.

Both will a raw array and `std::array`, you can pass a pointer to the start of the array and pass the size. If you find this more suitable for your case, then use that, but still raw array and `std::array` can do that. For raw array, it implicitly decays to a pointer, and with `std::array`, you must use `arr.data()` to get the pointer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! The only thing that I disagree with is the last comment about the size of the array / many templates accessing the size() function. I think @Brandon is correct that the size of the array is saved in the struct at compile time, which would then be in-lined everywhere it was used.

Comment: @user2654735 yes he is right. But what I meant is if you have a large function that must work with array of different sizes, then you could pass your array is a pointer to it's internal data + a size, if you wish your function not to be duplicated for every sizes.

Comment: This was a really great discussion! I hope it is helpful to other people. Guillaume Racicot, Justin, and Justin added a lot of really great insight into how the compiler works under the hood! Thanks again!